# jax b 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I want to create xml string from pojo.
I have a following pojo class

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "companyType", "leadType" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "EnrichmentPayload", namespace = "http://www.example.org/EnrichmentPayload_LM_2.0")
public class Schema {
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyType", required = true)
    CompanyType companyType;
    @XmlElement(name = "LeadType", required = true)
    LeadType leadType;

    public CompanyType getCompanyType() {
        return companyType;
    }

    public void setCompanyType(CompanyType companyType) {
        this.companyType = companyType;
    }

    public LeadType getLeadType() {
        return leadType;
    }

    public void setLeadType(LeadType leadType) {
        this.leadType = leadType;
    }
```

I have two classes CompanyType and LeadType on which I want namespace as well,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="CompanyType")
public class CompanyType {
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    boolean threshold_met;
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    boolean isActive;
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    String company_id;
...
}
```

And Lead Type

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "CompanyType")
    public class LeadType {
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        boolean threshold_met;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        int lead_id;
        @XmlElement(required = true)
...
}
```

Now i am marshalling the root element like this way:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.ss.dain.xmlcreator.Schema.class);

            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            //marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.org/EnrichmentPayload_LM_2.0");
            // marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.NameSpacePrefixMapper",
            // new NameSpaceMapper());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(schema, sw);
            xmlString = sw.toString();
```

it is throwing exception  while creating new instance

> JAXBContext.newInstance(com.ss.dain.xmlcreator.Schema.class);

Comment: You should add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Carefully read the complete error message, because it tells you exactly what you did wrong with the JAXB annotations. Post the entire error message in your post.

Comment: One problem is that class `LeadType` has an `@XmlType` annotation with `name = "CompanyType"`, the same as class `CompanyType`. You cannot have two different classes that map to the same XML type. That is probably a copy-and-paste mistake.